# Bootloader using mixed code using EXTERN

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, boot

I am creating simple calculator application on bootloader using mixed code including C language with Assembly Code.

My C language Code is (addasm.c):
       #include

```
      int main() {

bootmain();
return 0 ;

  }
   int bootmain()
  {
 int arg1, arg2, add, sub, mul, quo, rem ;

printf( "Enter two integer numbers : " );
scanf( "%d%d", &arg1, &arg2 );

/* Perform Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication & Division */
__asm__ ( "addl %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (add) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );
__asm__ ( "subl %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (sub) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );
__asm__ ( "imull %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (mul) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );

__asm__ ( "movl $0x0, %%edx;"
          "movl %2, %%eax;"
          "movl %3, %%ebx;"
           "idivl %%ebx;" : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2) );

printf( "%d + %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, add );
printf( "%d - %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, sub );
printf( "%d * %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, mul );
printf( "%d / %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, quo );
printf( "%d %% %d = %d\n", arg1, arg2, rem );
return 0;
 }
```

I had created bootmain() function in C which i need to use in assembly code.

My assembly code (ccode.asm) is :

```
 [BITS 16]   ; 16 bit code generation
 [ORG 0x7C00]    ; ORGin location is 7C00
 extern bootmain

  ;Main program
  main:      ; Main program label

  call bootmain

  ; End matter
   times 510-($-$$) db 0    ; Fill the rest of the sector with zeros
   dw 0xAA55        ; Boot signature
```

Now i am compiling this

```
    nasm -f elf -o main.o ccode.asm  #assemble our asm file
```

But It gives me error for ORG keyword that it is undefined keyword.

If i will remove this keyword then it will give me errorless output.

After removing ORG keyword I am compiling like this way:

```
  nasm -f elf -o main.o ccode.asm  #assemble our asm file
  gcc addasm.c main.o -o add_asm     #compile and link in one step
  ./add_asm
```

So I am using this final add_asm file and make my usb drive bootable by puting this add_asm file using Disk Explorer. 
But at booting it is showing message : Missing Operating System
So is this a problem of not using ORG in Assembly file.
This is mainly problem with ELF that i am using with NASM.But for external C function and for EXTERN keyword I need to use ELF.

The alternative code of ORG is :

```
  [Bits 16]
  extern bootmain
  start:
  mov ax, 07C0h ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
  add ax, 288 ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
  mov ss, ax
  mov sp, 4096
 call bootmain
 mov ax, 07C0h ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
 mov ds, ax
 times 510-($-$$) db 0; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
 dw 0xAA55 ; The standard PC boot signature
```

But it also does not work... It gives me same error as "Missing Operating System" at time of booting.

Is there any another way to include C function in assembly file (*.asm)?
I am stuck here. If there is any suggestion please give me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot turn a normal C program into a bootloader like that.

- The environment in which a bootloader runs is significantly different from a normal executable. In particular, it does not include a C library that you can link against (or, for that matter, any linker at all!), so functions like `printf()` and `scanf()` are not available unless you link in appropriate versions, which you are not doing.
- You are compiling your program as a 32-bit executable. An x86 system boots up in 16-bit mode. There is a significant amount of initialization which must take place to switch into that mode, none of which is present here.
- You are compiling your program as a Linux ELF (or possibly Windows PE?) executable. This is not the correct format for a bootloader.

Comment: Is there any another way to include C function in assembly file (*.asm)?

Comment: You seem to be confused. NASM is not a C compiler. It cannot compile or include C source files. Combining compiled C and ASM files is the job of the linker, not NASM.

Comment: Ok thank you. I got my mistake.I can't get memory initialization  at time of booting so it gives me error as "missing operating system". As I can not use ORG keyword with ELF so I can not initialize memory so I had tried alternative code for memory initialization given in edited part of my question.

Comment: Your problem is not memory initialization. **You are going about this completely wrong.** There are huge pieces of really important code which you haven't written, and the executable you're generating is not a valid bootloader. Please read through a tutorial on x86 "bare metal" programming before you continue.